# c++ boost::program_options: convert program_options/variables_map back to command line

Tags: c++, boost, command-line, boost-program-options, boost-process

I need to pass some specific arguments from one programm to another using boost::program_options and boost::process. Here is a simple example. In this example I need to pass all args stored in vm_slave to child process, but in common case I wanna pass one or more specific args from vm_slave.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace po = boost::program_options;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    po::options_description tester_options("Tester options");
    po::options_description slave_options("Slave options");

    tester_options.add_options()
        ("help,h", "Show help")
        ("iter,i", po::value<short>()->default_value(1), "TODO")
        ("modules,m", po::value<std::vector<string>>()->multitoken(), "TODO");

    slave_options.add_options()
        ("size,s", po::value<size_t>()->required(), "TODO")
        ("threads,t", po::value<short>()->default_value(1), "TODO");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::variables_map vm_slave;

    auto p0 = po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(tester_options).allow_unregistered().run();
    auto p1 = po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(slave_options).allow_unregistered().run();

    po::store(p0, vm);
    po::store(p1, vm);
    po::store(p1, vm_slave);

    // Do some stuff such as write help if needed
    // ...

    // I need call child process with all (or specific) args from vm_slave
    boost::process::ipstream pipe;
    boost::process::child cp(
        "slave" /* + vm_slave args */,
        boost::process::std_err > pipe,
        boost::process::std_out > pipe
    );

    cp.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

Of course I can do something like this:

```
ostringstream args;
for (const auto& arg : p1.options) {
    if (vm_slave.count(arg.string_key) == 0)
        continue;

    args << arg.string_key << " ";
    for (const auto& val : arg.value)
        args << val << " ";
}
string cmd_args = args.str();
```

But in this case some args stored in vm_slave by default is lost.

Or I can do this:

```
ostringstream args;
for (const auto& arg : vm_slave) {
    args << arg.first << " ";

    const auto& any_val = arg.second.value();
    if (boost::any_cast<size_t>(any_val))
        args << to_string(boost::any_cast<size_t>(any_val));
    else if (boost::any_cast<short>(any_val))
        args << to_string(boost::any_cast<size_t>(any_val));
    // And more and more casts...

    args << " ";
}
```

But now we have many any_cast...

If I just pass `argv` to child process, the child might fail because extra args presented (args like `iter` not intended for this application).

All this attempts seem bad to me.

**What is the proper way to convert parsed arguments back to command line?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no "proper way" - as composing command lines is not a feature of the library (neither is writing config-files).

I would use the parsed options. Unless you need to *interpret* the options you don't have to notify/store into a variable map at all:

```
std::vector<std::string> passthrough;
for (auto& opt : p1.options) {
    if (opt.unregistered || opt.string_key.empty())
        continue;

    assert(p1.description == &slave_options);

    auto& tok = opt.original_tokens;
    fmt::print("passing through {}: {}\n", opt.string_key, tok);
    passthrough.insert(passthrough.end(), tok.begin(), tok.end());
}
```

Demoing, using `printf` instead of `slave`:

```
if (vm.count("help")) {
    std::cout << tester_options << "\n\n" << slave_options << "\n";
} else {
    // demo using printf '- %q\n'
    passthrough.insert(passthrough.begin(), " - %q\n");
    bp::child cp("/usr/bin/printf", passthrough);

    cp.wait();
}
```

See it **[Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/jaMoGzedf)**

1. running `./sotest -i 1000 -m some modules to follow -h`

   ```
   Tester options:
     -h [ --help ]          Show help
     -i [ --iter ] arg (=1) TODO
     -m [ --modules ] arg   TODO


   Slave options:
     -s [ --size ] arg         TODO
     -t [ --threads ] arg (=1) TODO
   ```
2. running `./sotest -i 1000 -m some modules to follow -s=89 -t42`

   ```
   passing through size: ["-s=89"]
   passing through threads: ["-t42"]
    - '-s=89'
    - -t42
   ```
3. running `./sotest -i 1000 -m some modules to follow --size 89 --threads=42`

   ```
   passing through size: ["--size", "89"]
   passing through threads: ["--threads=42"]
    - --size
    - 89
    - '--threads=42'
   ```
4. running `./sotest -i 1000 -m some modules to follow -s 89 -t 42`

   ```
   passing through size: ["-s", "89"]
   passing through threads: ["-t", "42"]
    - -s
    - 89
    - -t
    - 42
   ```